# Frameに枠線をつけてその太さを変更したい

Tags: python, tkinter

python3.8
reliefで設定した枠線の太さを変更したいです。
tkで使えていた borderwidth= では枠自体は広がるようですが線は変わってくれません。
よろしくお願いします。

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("400x300")

fr = ttk.Frame(root)
fr.place(relwidth=1, relheight=1)

fr2 = ttk.Frame(fr, relief="solid", borderwidth=30) #ここ
fr2.place(anchor="center", relx=1/2, rely=1/2, width=200, height=150)
fr2.propagate(False)

label = ttk.Label(fr2, text="Label")
label.pack(pady=1)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

おそらく以下の内容により互換性が無いものと思われます。

[tkinter.ttk --- Tk のテーマ付きウィジェット](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/tkinter.ttk.html)

> Ttk を使う
>
> これにはプラットフォームをまたいでより良い見た目を得られるという、直接的な利益がありますが、ウィジェットは完全な互換性を持っているわけではありません。一番の違いは "fg" や "bg" やその他のスタイルに関係するウィジェットのオプションが Ttk ウィジェットから無くなっていることです。同じ (もしくはより良い) 見た目にするためには ttk.Style を使ってください。

[Ttk ウィジェット](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/tkinter.ttk.html#ttk-widgets)

> Ttk のコード:
>
> ```
> style = ttk.Style()
> style.configure("BW.TLabel", foreground="black", background="white")
>
> l1 = ttk.Label(text="Test", style="BW.TLabel")
> l2 = ttk.Label(text="Test", style="BW.TLabel")
> ```

上記を元にすると、`relief="solid"`の時だけ使える代替手段として`ttk.Frame`を入れ子にして外側フレームの背景色を枠線のように見せる方法が、以下のような感じで出来るでしょう。

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("400x300")

fr = ttk.Frame(root)
fr.place(relwidth=1, relheight=1)

s = ttk.Style()
s.configure('border.TFrame', background='#000000') ## 枠線用スタイルの色

bdrfr = ttk.Frame(fr, style='border.TFrame')       ## 枠線用の外側フレーム
bdrfr.place(anchor='center', relx=1/2, rely=1/2, width=200, height=150)
bdrfr.propagate(False)

clifr = ttk.Frame(bdrfr)                           ## 枠線用の内側フレーム
clifr.place(anchor='center', relx=1/2, rely=1/2, width=120, height=90)
clifr.propagate(False)

label = ttk.Label(clifr, text="Label")
label.pack(pady=1)

root.mainloop()
```

似たようなことが`LabelFrame`で出来るようですが、これはこれで使いこなすのにはノウハウが必要そうです。
[ttk: how to make a frame look like a labelframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12426315/9014308)
[How to Change Tkinter LableFrame Border Color](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42958927/9014308)
[【Python GUI Tkinterリファレンス】ttk.LabelFrame(ラベルフレーム)のオプション](https://suzutaka-programming.com/tkinter-ttk-labelframe-option/)